# Spring Integration DefaultMessageListenerContainer Transacted Message Not Rolledback

Tags: spring-integration

Expect the below configuration to rollback the `JMS` message to the backout queue, but it does not. The failed message is reaching the application's custom `ErrorChannel`. Please suggest why is the rollback not happening. Thanks

```
@Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer mqAdapterListenerContainer(final ConnectionFactory mqCachingConnectionFactory) {

    var defaultMessageListenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    defaultMessageListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(mqCachingConnectionFactory);
    defaultMessageListenerContainer.setSessionTransacted(true);

    return defaultMessageListenerContainer;
}

return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(mqAdapterListenerContainer)
                                .errorChannel(appErrorChannel))
                                .enrichHeaders(headerEnricherSpec -> headerEnricherSpec.errorChannel(appErrorChannel, true))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That JMS transaction can rollback only if listener throws exception, but since you do error handling via that `appErrorChannel`, there is no exception thrown to that JMS container.

So, you may still have a `.errorChannel(appErrorChannel)` and that error handling, but you need to re-throw some exception to let JMS container catch it rollback transaction respectively.

Comment: Thanks, would it had been the same behavior with default errorChannel as well?

Comment: Correct. A default global `errorChannel` has only a `LoggingHandler` by default which definitely swallows an exception as well - no re-throw.

Comment: Related ques please. Rollback worked perfectly fine after `.errorChannel(appErrorChannel)` was removed. However, the exception thrown was after the statement `.enrichHeaders(headerEnricherSpec -> headerEnricherSpec.errorChannel(appErrorChannel, true))`. Why did NOT the above statement redirect to errorrChannel, but to the Listener's 'ErrorHandler`?

Comment: Because it is Java: if you don't `catch` exception it is thrown up to the caller. Your `errorChannel` header enrichment does not have any effect downstream until you switch threads. Then the caller becomes a thread executor worker and already there that `errorChannel` header would have an effect. See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/error-handling.html#error-handling